# How to Get Count Vectorization of Dataframe of Arrays of Strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` as follows:

```
    words_separated
0   [lorem, ipsum]
1   [dolor, sit, amet]
2   [lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, lorem]
```

So each row contains an array of words. I would like to get something like this dataframe `df2`:

```
    lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet
0   1,     1,     0,     0,   0
1   0,     0,     1,     1,   1
2   2,     1,     1,     1,   1
```

So `df2` would have a column for each unique word that appeared in `df1`. The rows of `df2` would correspond to the rows in `df1` and record the number of times a word appeared in the corresponding row of `df1`. This is referred to as **Count Vectorization**.

I thought about using `MultiLabelBinarizer` like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

count_vec = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb = count_vec.fit(df["comment text"])
pd.DataFrame(mlb.transform(df["comment text"]), columns=[mlb.classes_])

    lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet
0   1,     1,     0,     0,   0
1   0,     0,     1,     1,   1
2   1,     1,     1,     1,   1
```

But this only returns if a word exists in a row, not how many times the word appeared, which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I can actually use scikit-learn's `CountVectorizer` for this task.

However, I first need to turn the arrays in `df1` to strings, since it is expecting strings:

```
text = df1["words_separated"].map(' '.join)

count_vec = CountVectorizer()
cv = count_vec.fit(text)

pd.DataFrame(cv.transform(text).toarray(), columns=[k for k, v in sorted(cv.vocabulary_.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])])
```